# Should I add HTTP "Transfer-Encoding" in Connection header?

Tags: http, connection, protocols, transfer-encoding

HTTP protocol states two things:

- `Transfer-Encoding` is a hop-by-hop header and it must be removed by proxies.
- Other hop-by-hop headers should be added in Connection header to tell proxies to remove them.

But, if everybody knows that `Transfer-Encoding` is a header that is removed anyway at every hop, then it is also necessary to add it in Connection header ?

Comment: "Transfer-Encoding [...] must be removed by proxies" I have a hard time believing this. Can you cite a relevant source? I couldn't find anything in RFC 2616 supporting this claim.

Comment: Here it is: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-13.5.1

Comment: Ebay does add `Connection: Transfer-Encoding`